# drupal clean url doesn't work after migration (nginx)

Tags: drupal, nginx

Server is Debian 7.

LEMP(nginx1.8, php5.6)

http://82.146.60.88/drupal.dev/

Any help?

here's my nginx drupal.conf

I've already tried rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1; in location @rewrite section, but didn't work for me((

```
server 
{
server_name drupal.dev; 
root /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal.dev;
gzip_static on;

location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
}
location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
}
location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
}
location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
}
location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {

        rewrite ^ /index.php;

}
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
}
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried with drush ? 
use drush wd-show --tail to see logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is working. The site is at http://82.146.60.88
No need for the /drupal.dev path

Comment: actually no(. I'm trying to place several sites as subfolders at root(/usr/share/nginx/html), this site is in ...html/drupal.dev, but front page is 404

Comment: OK, that makes sense. is it possible that the requests are being handled by a different server {} block. What happens if you visit http://drupal.dev/ ?

Comment: problem solved, looks like the way I was trying to make it work - is wrong (( (http://myIP/mySite). I'd got a domain and everything's fine now http://nicero.tk/